# out_of_range using std::map::at(const char*) except when compiling with /02

Tags: c++

I have a strange problem that I can't seem to make any headway on. I have a

`std::unordered_map<char*, MyType>`

that whenever I attempt to access with

```
at(const char*)
```

throws an out_of_range exception despite certainly containing the supplied key.

The only way it doesn't throw this exception is when built with /02 (Optimize for Speed), which is discovered when going to back debug and changing the optimization flag to disabled.

When I break at the place where I use at(), and look at my map, it looks perfectly fine, and the key is there, but the exception is still thrown.

Anyone ever have any issues like this?

```
std::unordered_map<char*, GUISetting> objectSettings = {{"Loot Containers", GUISetting("Loot Containers", LootContainerNames, true)}};

UI.objectSettings.at("Loot Containers").Enabled = iniReader.ReadBoolean("ObjectESP", "LootContainers", true);
```

Comment: Post some code that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would be much easier to help you then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::unordered_map` compares the keys using `==`, so it's checking whether your char pointers point to the same memory location, *not* that they point to equal strings.

If you want `std::unordered_map` to compare the strings that the char pointers point to, you need to pass the map a custom comparator as a template parameter. Or do it the easy way and use `std::string` as the key type.

Comment: Which also explains why it works when `/O2` is specified as it implies [/GF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0s0asdt.aspx)

Comment: I'm assuming then when compiled with /02 the compiler maps all duplicate strings to the same memory address and when no optimization is used there are separate locations for each string, even if they are identical?

Edit: just read about string pooling, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to @tuple_cat answer you could place all your string constants in one place:

`common_const.h`:

```
extern const char LOOT_CONTAINERS[];
extern const char SOMETHING_ELSE[];
```

`common_const.cc`:

```
const char LOOT_CONTAINERS[] = "Loot Containers";
const char SOMETHING_ELSE[] = "Something Else";
```

And then use this constants instead across code. Similar approach used in Chromium sources. But this will not work if you will try to somehow get the key from user input or any other source. Alternatively you could use `std::unordered_map<std::string, GUISetting>`.